# How to get the vaxis line in column chart of google api chart?

Tags: javascript, google-api

I am using column chart of corechart package in google api chart. In this chart i need for vertical axis line(yaxis line). How to get vertical axis line in columnchart.

I reffered this [link](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) for creating this chart

**Actual**

[image]

**Expected**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make Y-axis number not String.

here is the code : Copy and paste this is google Code Playground.

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Austria', 'Bulgaria' ],
    [12,  133,    400],
    [21,  153,    366],
    [20,  155,    240],
    [27,  160,    134],
    [10,  196,    393],
    [8,  190,    232]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
            width:600, height:400,
            vAxis: {title: "Year",ticks: [{v:100, f:"100$"},{v:150, f:"150$"},{v:200, f:"200$"},{v:300, f:"300$"}]},
            hAxis: {title: "Cups",ticks: [{v:4, f:"3-4"},{v:8, f:"5-9"},{v:10, f:"9-13"},{v:14, f:"13-14"},{v:20, f:"15-20"}]} }
      );
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply and kindly tell me how to give the tick mark of all values in vertical axis(yaxis).

Comment: You can Customize the tick by hAxis.ticks,vAxis.ticks Configuration Options in gggole graph.  See the Link   https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

Comment: we are using string values like 0-5, 5-16, 17-25, 25-37.How can i use this value to draw the line(y axis line).

Comment: Can you please provide  sample picture and data ?. Right now it is not clear to me, what you want .