# Google API Column Chart Verticl Axis Line

Tags: google-visualization

I am looking for how to plot the vertical axis line on the google api column chart?
the sample question asked by one of the member long time back, but there was no reply

[How to get the vaxis line in column chart of google api chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120364/how-to-get-the-vaxis-line-in-column-chart-of-google-api-chart)

any suggestion how to achieve this and any sample please

Comment: What do you mean "there was no reply"? The question you linked to has an accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry i might be wrong. Can you please assist me how to have the vertical line on the the graph?

Comment: It is not clear how what you are asking is not a duplicate of the question you linked to. If your question is not a duplicate, please expand it to include sample code, the actual output you see, and an explanation of the expected output you would like to see.

Comment: Hi Josh, I resolved myself. thanks for your time on this