# Google Chart: is it possible to use Strings for the x axis?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

So I tried messing around with my charts and noticed that integers/floats/dates work perfectly fine for the x axis, but the moment that you put in a string, it blows up.

I'm trying to graph a: Word/Count graph, but unfortunately I can't seem to be able to put strings in the x axis. Is this allowed in Google Charts, or is it strictly int/floats/dates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use vAxis and hAxis property as below

```
google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
  draw(data,
       {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
        width:600, height:400,
        vAxis: {title: "Year",ticks: [{v:100, f:"100$"},{v:150, f:"150$"},{v:200, f:"200$"},{v:300, f:"300$"}]},
        hAxis: {title: "Cups",ticks: [{v:4, f:"3-4"},{v:8, f:"5-9"},{v:10, f:"9-13"},{v:14, f:"13-14"},{v:20, f:"15-20"}]} }
  );
```

for more detail check this [How to get the vaxis line in column chart of google api chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120364/how-to-get-the-vaxis-line-in-column-chart-of-google-api-chart)

Answer (score 4):

Just define your column to be of type `string` and there is no issue. Do note that with a string major column, all rows will be evenly spaced among the chart.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        data.addRows([
        ['Jan', 1],
        ['Feb', 5],
        ['Mar', 2],
        ['Apr', 3]
    ]);
```

To also use vertical lines in your chart you can not use column type `string` but you have to use either `number`, `float` or `date`. To still use strings as x-axis labels you can use `ticks` like in the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/j29Pt/417/